# How to quickly edit values in table in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Aside from context menu -> "Edit Top 200 Rows" from Object Explorer, is there a quick way to open a table in Edit mode where I can just quickly modify the value of a cell?

I need to be able to page past the first 200 rows. And I dont want to write "insert" script for every minor tweak I need to do... I don't understand why SMS doesn't offer quick access to a paged table editor (like Navicat).

Answer (score 161, accepted):

In Mgmt Studio, when you are editing the top 200, you can view the SQL pane - either by right clicking in the grid and choosing Pane->SQL or by the button in the upper left.  This will allow you to write a custom query to drill down to the row(s) you want to edit.

But ultimately mgmt studio isn't a data entry/update tool which is why this is a little cumbersome.

Comment: If you allow your user to do something (like edit the tables), it should be easy to do so. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: This only works if you are using a single table, i.e. no joins. Once you start joining 2 or 3 tables, you can no longer do this. It would be interesting if there were any other solutions.

Comment: Yeah, if you join in another table it changes the cells to Read Only :/

Comment: And when you want to execute the SQL its NOT the usual "execute" button (F5) - its right click on the pane > "Run query" (Ctrl-R)

Comment: If "mgmt studio isn't a data entry/update tool" - then which is? Genuine interest, no hidden sarcasm. I would love a tool like that.

Answer (score 60):

Go to Tools > Options. In the tree on the left, select SQL Server Object Explorer. Set the option "Value for Edit Top  Rows command" to 0. It'll now allow you to view and edit the entire table from the context menu.

Comment: ...which is not necessarily a very good idea, if your table has millions of rows.....

Comment: why don't just enter the desired value for edit Top (n) Rows  ie I entered 1000 rows from  "Server Object Explorer" option as described by  Adam..
giving +1

Comment: @marc_s - yes, but is there a way to edit the sql which gets the top N rows for editing ? Got it - Just choose "Edit Top xyz rows", press Ctrl + 3 in the edit grid region (or click "Show SQL Pane") and edit the query...
But please note that this will work only for the query that doesn't contain "join"

Comment: I don't think this allows you to edit the table from the context menu. If I right click a row returned from a select query, there's no option to edit the value (at least in SSMS 18).

Answer (score 3):

Brendan is correct.  You can edit the Select command to edit a filtered list of records.  For instance `"WHERE dept_no = 200"`.

Comment: This answer could be improved if it said what to click on to edit the query.  I am doing edit top 200 and then I want to edit the query.  I don't know how to do that.

Comment: To bring up the edit-grid's sql editor, just press Ctrl-3 while focus is on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post but I figure to simplify the answer which I saw Paul and matty answered.

So yes you can change "Value for Edit Top Rows command" to 0 but that will list out everything you don't need. I personally like using "WHERE" so I can target specifically what I need.. so this is what I have done with SMSS v19.3.

1. I do the "Edit Top 200 rows" by right clicking the table I want to modify.
2. I press Ctrl+3 (This assumes that table that popped up is selected). This control will open the query box which you can now edit.
3. Add the "WHERE" targetting the field you want to filter for. You can also remove the "TOP (200)" if you wish but since I'm target for a specific value, I normally don't have 200 of those records.
4. Refresh the table by pressing Ctrl+R or right click on the table and click "Execute SQL"
5. Now you can double click the value you want to edit.