# Edit SQL Server records by select in new query

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I know I can edit records in SQL Server Management Studio like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543478/how-to-edit-data-in-result-grid-in-sql-server-management-studio), But I want to edit records in new query and without right click on table and select edit.

For example I have `student` table and query below:

```
select * from student
where ID = 1
```

Result is:

[image: my table]

I want to edit `Fname` in this record but this window isn't editable.

I read too many post but I could not find a way to do it.Is there a way to do it in SQL Server Management Studio?

**Edit**

I know I can use `Update` query for edit records but I want to edit in grid directly.

[image: edit]

**without** `Edit Top 100 Rows` like this:

[image: edit menu]

Comment: No you can't. As @Hadi Hassan mentioned run update statement.

Comment: not with SSMS. If you want to be able to edit records in a grid while your query is complex (SSMS finds a join complex it seems) than use another tool than SSMS

Comment: look
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543478/how-to-edit-data-in-result-grid-in-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543478/how-to-edit-data-in-result-grid-in-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: With `Edit Top 200 Rows', you can edit data in grid and you can edit **NOT ONLY** top 200 rows.

Comment: @qxg I know with `Edit Top 200 Rows` I can edit all records but I don't want to use `Edit Top 200 Rows`.

Answer (score 1):

After you opened 'Edit Top 200 Rows' pane,

1. Press `Ctrl + 3` to 'Show Query Pane';
2. Modify default query with your filter;
3. Press `Ctrl + R` to execute your query.

You can find related button ins `Query Designer` toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Update Statement

```
update t set t.Fname = 'NewValue'
from student
where ID= 1
```

Or

Right click on the table from the `object explorer`, then `Edit or Modify` "depends on the version of your ssms", then click on show sql pane, modify the query and the Grid will be editable as long as there is no joining with other tables.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You need update statement.

```
update student set Fname = 'NewValue'
where ID= 1
```

You can learn more here
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp