# Changing a value in a column manually with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have a row in my table, and I want to change one of the values in a column. For example... I want to change the status in a particular row from "Development" to "Production".

In MySql Workbench there was an option to click the value and you could simply type in the value you wanted. Is there a similar method in Microsoft SQL Server without typing a SQL statement?

Comment: Please don't treat your SQL Server database like a spreadsheet. You should use an `UPDATE` statement in a query window, not some Edit grid. Among other reasons, so that you can actually test what you wrote, roll it back if needed, store it in source control, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the table you want to edit and then choose *Edit first 200 records*.

In that table you can modify the values. It will be saved instantly.

Comment: Oh wow this is great! What if I wanted to edit say the 400th row in the table?

Comment: Then click on the icon [SQL]. The tooltip says something like *Show SQL window*. There you could edit the predefined query and change the 200 to 400

Answer (score 2):

Following up with the accepted answer, if you wanted to edit more rows than "Edit Top 200 Rows" gives you, **you need to have the "Query Designer" selected** in order to show the [SQL] button.

1) right click on the "New Query" button

2) select the "Query Designer" option

3) now your toolbar will look like this...

[image]

After you select the "Edit Top 200 Rows," you will see the SQL button (shown in yellow) that will show you the query where you can change the 200 to whatever you'd like.

I was having issues finding the "[SQL]" button, so hopefully the screenshot will help.

Comment: for more details on how to edit more/less rows, go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535469/how-to-quickly-edit-values-in-table-in-sql-server-management-studio