# How can i update a table using this view

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have 3 tables called Airlines,Destinations and PriceTable.

The Airlines table has two columns - Airline_ICAO_Code and Airline. The Destinations table has two columns - Airport_ICAO_Code and Destination. The PriceTable has these columns - ID,Airport_ICAO_Code, Airline_ICAO_Code,Departure,Price and RouteStaus.

The PK in PriceTable is ID.The PK in Airlines table is Airline_ICAO_Code. The PK in Destinations table is Airport_ICAO_Code. The columns Airport_ICAO_Code and Airline_ICAO_Code in the price table are FKs.

**I created a view called InputFlightPrices which i want to use to update the PriceTable** which stores the flight prices. The reason im using the view to do this is that it allows me to see clearly what airline routes need updating as its difficult to determine the airline and destination from the codes.

This is the view code:

```
Create View InputFlightPrices
As
Select ID,Airline,Destination,AirportName,Price,Departure,RouteStatus
From Airlines As a
    Join PriceTable As p
On  a.Airline_ICAO_Code = p.Airline_ICAO_Code
    Join Destinations As d
    On  d.Airport_ICAO_Code = p.Airport_ICAO_Code;
```

I want the view to display all airlines a-z but I cannot use an Order By clause in the view.

I therefore ran the query below on the view to order the airlines in the view A-Z

```
Select * from InputFlightPrices
Order By Airline Asc
```

The resulting view from the above statement displays correctly but **it does not allow me to edit the records in it in order to update the table.**

Is there a solution.

Thanks for any help offered.

Im editing this in response to Philpxy to try and clarify what i want:

1. I want to update a table called PriceTable which contains flight prices.
2. The Airline and Destination columns within the PriceTable contain codes. It is difficult to know what airline and destination to update from these codes so I created a view called InputFlightPrices which shows the Airline and Destination names. This makes it easy to enter the prices for the correct routes.
   The problem with the View is that the Airline column is not sorted. Records belonging to an Airline are scattered throughout the table. This could lead to me missing some routes that need to be updated.
3. Therefore I created a select statement which Ordered the View by Airline A-Z.
4. The problem that i have now is that I cannot update the PriceTable using this View(the result of select statement) as It does not allow me to edit it.I tried to edit by clicking it directly using the GUI.

I hope thats clear.

[image: Table examples]

Comment: One doesn't update records in a view; one updates records in a table.  Can you clarify what you want to do?  Sample data and desired results is most helpful.

Comment: Where is your update code ?

Comment: order by is only important for viewing data, your update statement should have a more concrete logic for updating a row. If your view doesnt allow you to update records, check limitation for updating using view, you cannot issue an update statement if it affects more than one underlying tables.

Comment: Atleast post the `view`. You cannot update a view if it has `group by`

Comment: I edited the Qs above. I tried to use SSMS to edit the rows directly in the view that was returned by the select statement. Im using the view to update the underlying table.

Comment: im not using an update statemnet. im clicking on the table and trying to edit it that way. read above

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear exactly what you want to do. That includes being clear about what related options you're not interested in.  And even if you are using a gui the nature of the update can affect the answer. Question info does not belong in comments.

Comment: Please give your table definitions. Also exactly what behaviour "it does not allow me to edit the records in it" means in terms of what your edit involves and the system response. Please give exact data for an example.

Answer (score 0):

> As you have multiple joins in view, the update may not update the records correctly. You can use triggers here to update the table.

Comment: i have multiple joins but the only columns that will be updated come from the PriceTable so that should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to edit your `Select * from InputFlightPrices Order By Airline Asc` query per answers to [How to quickly edit values in table in SQL Server Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1535469/3404097):

> In Mgmt Studio, when you are editing the top 200, you can view the SQL
> pane - either by right clicking in the grid and choosing Pane->SQL or
> by the button in the upper left. This will allow you to write a custom
> query to drill down to the row(s) you want to edit.
>
> Go to Tools > Options. In the tree on the left, select SQL Server
> Object Explorer. Set the option "Value for Edit Top Rows command" to
> 0. It'll now allow you to view and edit the entire table from the context menu.

Re updating when the query result involves a view:

From SQL Server 2014 [CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

> The SELECT clauses in a view definition cannot include the following:
>
> - An ORDER BY clause, unless there is also a TOP clause in the select list of the SELECT statement
>
>   The ORDER BY clause is used only to determine the rows that are returned by the TOP or OFFSET clause in the view definition. The ORDER
>   BY clause does not guarantee ordered results when the view is queried,
>   unless ORDER BY is also specified in the query itself.

[...]

> You can modify the data of an underlying base table through a view, as
> long as the following conditions are true:
>
> - Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, must reference columns from only one base table.

[...]

> Generally, the
> Database Engine must be able to unambiguously trace modifications from
> the view definition to one base table.

Per the last sentence: If you want to update a base table for a particular row then it has to be just one base table's columns, columns of some key from that base table must be in the view (UNIQUE NOT NULL or PRIMARY KEY), and you must not be updating those columns.

Otherwise when you ask to update some row in the view it's not clear what row in what base table is to be updated.

See also SQL Server 2014 [Modify Data Through a View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx#SSMSProcedure).

Comment: I will be updating 2 columns from just 1 table(PriceTable) in the view. they are Departure and Price

Comment: Read the comments on your question and put the information in your question. Eg here you have said nothing about keys yet my answer says that they matter. How do you expect to get more help if you do not give the information that the help so far is telling you to give?

Comment: Regarding "Mgmt Studio, when you are editing the top 200, you can view the SQL pane - either by right clicking in the grid and choosing Pane->SQL or by the button in the upper left." This only works if you are using a single table, i.e. no joins. Once you start joining 2 or 3 tables, you can no longer do this