# In SqlSvr 2008R2, how would a search a Table for a record, then edit THAT record

Tags: sql-server, record

In my SQL Server 2008r2 database I have a Table with over 25000 records in it. when I search for the record i need to edit, it returned 6 possible, but it wont let me edit. I can just open the table and go through all 25000 records, which is painful. I would like to be able to search for the right records, then be able to edit those records.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some of the code/commands you have tried using to solve this, it might be able to help someone answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to quickly edit values in table in SQL Server Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535469/how-to-quickly-edit-values-in-table-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to write an UPDATE. I could give you an example on how to do it, but since you didn't post any code, I can only give you the examples on the documentation.

Review the [documentation on UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SSMS, this may be helpful: [How to quickly edit values in table in SQL Server Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535469/how-to-quickly-edit-values-in-table-in-sql-server-management-studio)

If you aren't using SSMS, knowing what UI you're using would be helpful.

Comment: This can sometimes get the rows mixed up too and you end up editing the wrong one. At least back in the day, they may have fixed that "feature" by now. But writing an update statement is a much better approach.

Comment: I agree with Sean Lange (as usual). SSMS is not made to edit values through the graphic interface. I just hope that they remove that option from future releases.